# Corrigindo erro NaN

Tags: javascript, html

Onde está errado para gerar este erro? Acredito que seja no `var preco = $(this).next("input.preco").val();` pois se substituir o `Number(preco)` por `Number(qtde)` funciona, mas preciso que seja o `Number(preco)`, claro.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        var qtde = $(this).next("input").val();
        var preco = $(this).next("input.preco").val();
        total += Number(qtde) * Number(preco);
    });

    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> 
<input type="number" value="1" min="1"> 
<input type="number" class="preco" value="8">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> 
<input type="number" value="1" min="1"> 
<input type="number" class="preco" value="24">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> 
<input type="number" value="1" min="1"> 
<input type="number" class="preco" value="17">
<br><br>
<span>Total:</span><input type="text" id="total" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o `preco` é o próximo input após a quantidade (`qtde`), você consegue usar o `next` com base nele, exemplo:

```
var preco = $(this).next("input").next(".preco").val();
```

Veja o código completo:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        var qtde = $(this).next("input").val();
        var preco = $(this).next("input").next(".preco").val();
        total += Number(qtde) * Number(preco);
    });

    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> 
<input type="number" value="1" min="1"> 
<input type="number" class="preco" value="8">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> 
<input type="number" value="1" min="1"> 
<input type="number" class="preco" value="24">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"> 
<input type="number" value="1" min="1"> 
<input type="number" class="preco" value="17">
<br><br>
<span>Total:</span><input type="text" id="total" />
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!